# Select all the contents of a mysql table, and echo a list of the corresponding categories

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, if-statement

I have been working on my php skills for some time, but i don't even know how to start structuring this function.

Lets say i have 20 entries in a table called Cars, and that each of these cars has its own unique auto increment id, and the id of the makers in another column. I then have another table which contains the names of the car Makers. So for example 5 cars have car maker id A, another 3 have car maker id B and so on (where A and B are the id number of the car makers).

How would i go about searching the Cars table, then echoing a list of the car makers in alphabetical order?

I can figure out how to echo a list of the car makers by echoing the name each time one is found, but this would mean having the same car maker name 5 times instead of just once, and i don't know how to alphabetize it.

Here is a more graphic example to explain what i mean in case i wasn't very clear.

Cars table:

```
1 - WhatCar - 3
2 - WhoCar  - 3
3 - TheCar  - 2
4 - SomeCar - 3
5 - ThisCar - 1
6 - ACar    - 3
```

Makers table:

```
1 - AMaker
2 - DMaker
3 - CMaker
4 - BMaker
```

Desired output:

```
AMaker
CMaker
DMaker
```

Also, if i had a third table, containing 3 entries, with only the auto increment id and the id of a car, as such:

```
1 - 3
2 - 4
3 - 6
```

How would i make the script produce a Makers list that only corresponds to this "filter" using an if statement? (As in if X then parse the Cars table, elseif Y parse only the cars in Cars table specified by this third table)

I think its a simple function but i cant seem to picture it in my head nor find a suitable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is rather simple . . . a `join` and `distinct` and `order by`.

Making some assumptions about the field names:

```
select distinct m.maker
from cars c join
     makers m
     on c.makerid = m.makerid
order by m.maker;
```

If you had a third table, you would handle this with either an additional `join` or `where` condition:

```
select distinct m.maker
from cars c join
     makers m
     on c.makerid = m.makerid join
     thirdtable tt
     on c.carid = tt.carid
order by m.maker;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.makers
FROM Makers A 
INNER JOIN Cars C ON A.MakerId = C.MakerId 
ORDER BY A.makers
```

For Second question

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.makers
FROM Makers A 
INNER JOIN Cars C ON A.MakerId = C.MakerId 
LEFT JOIN CarFilter CF ON C.CarId = CF.CarId 
WHERE CASE WHEN **Condition to parse Cars table** THEN 1 
           WHEN **Condition to parse Cars filter table** THEN 1 CF.Id 
           ELSE 1 
      END) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY A.makers
```